# how to dispay 3 divs inline

Tags: html, css

i have 3 divs, i want for a navbar, i need the navbar to be responsive

They cant stay inline on a width less than 800px, what im i doing wrong

```css
.logo {
    width: 18%;
    min-width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.middle {
   width: 60%; 
   display: inline-block;
}
.user {
   width: 18%;
   min-width: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo"> LOGO </div>
    <div class="middle"> About, contact </div>
    <div class="user"> signin </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here (on Firefox) they stay inline until 598px width...

Answer (score 0):

Use display: flex; in .navbar

The default flex direction is row so that should align your 3 divs horizontally .

And remove display properties from the child divs.
Give them flex-basis for respective widths

Comment: Hi, your answer would be excellent with a correct piece of code edit and improve it, please